# Issue using reply mail management (MC) and email to case (SC)

Tags: marketing-cloud, email2case, servicecloud, reply-mail-management

We use both RMM (MC) and email2case (SC), only we experience an issue.

When somebody replies on an email that is sent from Marketing Cloud. Their reply is forwarded with RMM to the address support@example.com. This triggers the email to case, a case is created.

The only problem is, the email address of the contact on the case is re-written from jake@test.com to jakeattest.com@reply.example.com. Therefore, a new contact is created, instead of connecting it to the existing contact with the email address jake@test.com.

Does anybody have a solution to this?

As far as I understand, disabling DMARC forward reply re-write will give issues with forwarding the emails at all. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_dmarc_fwd_reply_rewrite.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to contact Marketing Cloud Support. They are able to make the necessary back-end RMM settings changes that will stop the email address from appearing in this way.

Comment: I think that you mean disabling the DMARC forward reply re-write. From my understanding, this will give you deliverability issues. 

Since you try to forward an email through your Marketing Cloud IP address without any verification from the domain owner?

Answer (score 0):

When DMARC Forward Reply Rewrite is enabled, RMM rewrites email headers to avoid rejection. The From Name is rewritten as `<From Name> <user> at <domain>`. For example, a subscriber reply from Teresa Lee, tlee@example.com, is rewritten as "Teresa Lee tlee at example.com". The From Email is rewritten as `<user>.<domain>@<reply subdomain>`. For example, a subscriber reply from tlee@example.com with the reply subdomain email.company.com is rewritten as tlee.example.com@email.company.com.

Marketing Cloud maintains an internal list of domains that publish restrictive DMARC policies. This list is referenced to determine which email replies headers to rewrite.

All accounts are enabled to rewrite headers, as necessary, to handle most email forwarding scenarios. If that potentially works better for your workflow, the functionality can be disabled upon request, or it can be configured to always rewrite headers for all replies. Contact Marketing Cloud support for assistance.

Article- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_dmarc_fwd_reply_rewrite.htm&type=5